# How to use a model from a Django project in another Python script

Tags: python, django

I have a directory which contains a Django project with a models.py in which I have defined some models.  I have another directory somewhere else and which has a Python script.  In this script I would like to import one of the models "Foo" from models.py.

With the table "Foo", I want to create entries, update, get, etc...  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run django.setup()

```
import os
import django

script_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='myapp.settings'
django.setup()
```

now you can import your models as normal

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql alchemy

You can add the mainscript as part of the django project

You can serve content using Django Rest Framework, the database connection happens when you access through manage.py, the table is available to anyone with permissions.

tl:dr; You need a connection to said database

Answer (score 0):

If your django project is within your PYTHONPATH you can access it anywhere otherwise you can import it with importlib.machinery or make a .pth file and specify there the path to your django

```
import importlib.machinery
loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('modulename', 'path/to/module')
module = loader.load_module()
```

and now you can use module to access your models.py if you used the path to  your django app to load the model

or add it with the sites module

```
import sites, 
sites.addsitedir('/path/to/your/module.py')
```